# jQuery find className not working for second click function

Tags: jquery

I have the below code where when the user clicks on the month, just that particular months content is shown, and when the user clicks on the year, all the months content for that year is shown, but I'm having trouble making it work.

HTML

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="year15">2015
      <ul>
        <li class="jan15">JAN</li>
        <li class="feb15">FEB</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="year14">2014
      <ul>
        <li class="jan14">JAN</li>
        <li class="feb14">FEB</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="months">

  <div class="year15">
    <div class="jan15">
      <p>january 2015</p>
    </div>
    <div class="feb15">
      <p>february 2015</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="year14">
    <div class="jan14">
      <p>january 2014</p>
    </div>
    <div class="feb14">
      <p>february 2014</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

jQuery - This makes all months content show for that year

```
$('ul > li').click(function() {
  var className = $(this).attr('class');

  $('.months > div').hide();

  if ($('.' + className).length > 0) {
    $('.' + className).show();
  }
});
```

jQuery - This makes the individual months content show

```
$('ul li ul li').click(function() {
  var className = $(this).attr('class');

  $('.months > div').children().hide();

  if ($('.' + className).length > 0) {
    $('.' + className).show();
  }
});
```

If I put the 2 codes together, clicking on the year first then the months works fine, but when clicking back on the year, or clicking on the months before the year breaks the year code form working.

I managed to make it work using the below, but the code will be ridiculously long if I add in all the years.

```
if ($(this).hasClass('year14')) {
    $('.months .year14').children().show();
  } else if ($(this).hasClass('year15')) {
    $('.months .year15').children().show();
```

Is there a way around this, or is my final jQuery code the only way to go?

https://jsfiddle.net/fk7snLct/

Comment: Side note: There's never any need for things like `if ($('.' + className).length > 0) { $('.' + className).show(); }` with jQuery. jQuery is *set-based*. Just `$('.' + className).show();` is all you need. If there are no matching elements, it just doesn't do anything (it's not an error).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you, will update accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('li[class*="year"]').click(function(e) {
    var className = $(this).attr('class').split(' ').pop();
    $('div[class*="year"] div').show();
    $('div[class*="year"]').hide();
    $('div.'+className).show();
  console.log(className);
});
$('li[class*="year"] > ul > li').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var className = $(this).attr('class').split(' ').pop();
    $('div[class*="year"] div').hide();
    $('div[class*="year"]').hide();
    $('div.'+className).parent().show();
    $('div.'+className).show();
  console.log(className);
});
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/72dvf3b8/

Comment: Thank you works great as it is, but if I add more than one class to the li, the code no longer works.

Comment: @tatty edited my code (and fiddle) to use with multiple classes. beware that the yearN and monthN classes must be positioned as last class (means `class="foo bar year15"`)

Comment: Thanks again, works a charm. Just one more quick question. For the li I have an `addClass` which runs when the li is clicked on and adds the class after yearN which makes the code not work, so if I put yearN at the start and remove the `.pop()`, would this be valid?

Comment: Replace .pop() with [0] so it will return first element of the array created by .split(' ')

Answer (score 1):

I like this aprouch, I think is readable.

Javascript:

```
$('li').on('click',function(event){

  if (event.target !== this)
    return;

   var data = $(this).data();
   var $months = $('.months');
   var $year = $months.find('[data-year="'+data.year+'"]');

   $months.find('.year, .month').hide();

   switch(data.type){
    case 'year':
        $year.show().find('.month').show();
        break;
    case 'month':
        $year.show().find('[data-month="'+data.month+'"]').show();
        break;
   }


});
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="year" data-type='year' data-year='2015'>
      2015
      <ul>
        <li class="month" data-type='month' data-year='2015' data-month='jan'>JAN</li>
        <li class="month" data-type='month' data-year='2015' data-month='feb'>FEB</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="year" data-type='year' data-year='2014'>2014
      <ul>
        <li class="month" data-type='month' data-year='2014' data-month='jan'>JAN</li>
        <li class="month" data-type='month' data-year='2014' data-month='feb'>FEB</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="months">

  <div class="year" data-year="2015">
    <div class="month" data-month='jan'>
      <p>january 2015</p>
    </div>
    <div class="month" data-month='feb'>
      <p>february 2015</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="year" data-year="2014">
    <div class="month" data-month='jan'>
      <p>january 2014</p>
    </div>
    <div class="month" data-month='feb'>
      <p>february 2014</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fk7snLct/1/